# What is the "Home" feature of the Stepper Motor Driver IC (DRV8811)?

Tags: stepper-motor, control, texas-instruments

While doing research on efficient methods for driving stepper motors I came across the Texas Instrument IC [DRV8811](http://www.ti.com/product/drv8811). This particular device has a *Home* feature that is explained very little. The datasheet has a Step Table that gives information regarding output phase, etc. This table has a *Home* state defined as the fifth step when operating in 1/8 step mode.

[image]

Is this *Home* state simply the fifth step offset from whatever arbitrary position the stepper motor happens to be at when powered on?

The device also has a *Home* pin that appears to pulse whenever the driver IC has reached this state. The only information given in the datasheet is:

> Logic low when at home state of step table, logic high at other states

I have never before seen such a feature, so I wanted to verify exactly what this feature was prior to committing to a purchase and design.

[image]

Comment: It's certainly for calibration purposes - steppers are especially interesting in that they don't need encoders; however the downside is that you only know for sure how much they turned since power on. When starting the angle can be anything. ALSO steppers might miss a step, and drift over time. Usually we use a limit switch for the "home" position, or "reset" if you prefer (when booting and regularly, run it towards it forever until it hits it), but without giving it much thought it may be an alternate way of doing it.

Comment: That relates to a larger control system that a stepper motor is a part of. It is true for a 3d printer or other like device at start up 1st thing is a "homing phase" where the axis are driven positive, then back until contact with an end stop sensor (switch or optical), the controller will 'dance' on the stop averaging its exact triggering position based on step count. Then walks slowly onto the stop to catch the exact point it trips, step counts 0ed out, and reports its at the 'home' 000 XYZ position. No idea what motor/driver home means, I assumed it was a whole step cog, but it seems not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be getting the HOME pulse every 4 steps in full-step, or every 8, 16, or 32 steps in microstepping modes. In microstepping, the state table contains "values" for the current to be sent in each of the two windings to set the rotor in a particular position relative to the full step (which doesn't need a state table). IIRC this is the position with the highest holding torue.

The microstepping waveform vaguely resembles one period of a sinusoid; in the table you've posted last column shows the "position" or angle corresponding to the microstep on this sinusoid.

Comment: Ive always thought it was used in micro stepping to indicate when the rotor was at a 'full step cog' position. Like if the driver turned off output it wouldn't rotate to the nearest neutral state, as its already at a normal full step position. Which I suppose would be the point of highest holding power, teeth fully aligned on a position with just that coil phase energized. However I have never come across confirmation of this, and searches return the homing sequence of the larger system thanks to search engines treating their users like morons and mangling their queries....